# Wordpress different language footer text

Tags: php, translation

I am new to WordPress, and I have a problem building my website. I use the Sydney theme and Polylang plugin for my multilanguage website.

I have build a website in 4 different languages and now I would like to have a different footer text for every language in the sub footer part.

For e.g. where it says in English language  '**Copyright I Privacy policy**' ', with the hyperlink on `provacypolicy/en`, that I have created. For the German start page the subfooter language should auto change in '**Copyright I Datenschutz**', with the hyperlink from Datenschutz on the German page with `privacypolicy/de` that I have created. And also the same for the other languages.

I tried to edit that in the `footer.php` but I had no luck.

My existing code for `<div class="site-info container">` in `footer.php` is:

```
© <?php echo date("Y"); ?> | Company name | All rights reserved | <a href=
"http://localhost/companyname/wordpress/privacy-policy/">Privacy policy</a>
```

When I go to my german language it should change to:

```
© <?php echo date("Y"); ?> | Company name | Alle Rechte vorbehalten | <a href=
"http://localhost/companyname/wordpress/datenschutz/">Datenschutz</a>
```

And the same for other two languages.

---

#### I RESOLVED THE ISSUE.

For anyone that will have the same problem, use the `if - endif` code in your footer.php.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately, your issue seems to be with the Polylang plugin, not with WordPress in general. You're more likely to get an answer at the plugin author's forum: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/polylang

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with poly lang, because the free version of polylang probably doesn't have this function for subfooter. I think you can change the footer with polylang, add it as widget for different languages, but not for subfooter. I tried various 'if-else' codes in Edit footer.php, but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean the subfooter text is hardcoded in the theme?

Comment: I changed the original text in the theme "Powered by..." to my in footer.php and added the link for the text to new site, but only in my primary language. Now when you choose another language, the subfooter text doesn't change.

Comment: I would like that the text '2018 I Privacy policy' changes to '2018 I Datenschutz' when you choose German language, and the same for other languages that I have on my site.

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us the code that you add to the `footer.php`? Maybe someone sees the reason why it is not working.

Comment: I resolved the issue. For anyone that will have the same problem, use the if - endif code in your footer.php.

Comment: I have been told that this code is not the best choise, due to the problems that will arise when I update the site. This sub-footer will change due the fact that I changed the original theme, instead of the child theme. I donot know if this is true, hope not, but I do not have any other idea how to solve this problem, except as the one I made with if-endif.

Comment: If you have found the answer, please include it as an answer and accept it. If you do it as an edit to the question, this question will remain flagged 'unsolved' in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For the text in the theme to be able to be translated, the text should be passed as an argument through the localization functions `__()`, `_e()`.

> echo __( 'Sample text to display', 'theme-textdomain' );
>     _e( 'Sample text to display', 'theme-textdomain' );

More functions and details you can find [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#localization-functions)

---

In your case it could look like this:

```
© <?php 
echo date("Y"); 
$page_id = 'ID_of_privacy_policy_page';

if ( function_exists('pll_get_post') )
    $page_id = pll_get_post( $page_id );
$p_link = get_the_permalink($page_id);
$p_title = get_post_field('post_title', $page_id);

printf(' | %s | %s | <a href="%s">%s</a>', 
    'Company name',
    __('All rights reserved', 'some_textdomain'),
    esc_url($p_link),
    esc_html($p_title)
);
```

`$page_id` can be hardcoded or set with `$page_id = get_page_by_path('privacy-policy')->ID;`.

```
$page_id = pll_get_post( $page_id );
```

The obove line will get ID of "Privacy policy" page in current language.

The next step is to prepare a files with the translation `de_DE.po`, `de_DE.mo` and for 2 other languages. Edit existing files in your theme or create new ones if needed. A list of sample tools is available on the [codex website](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/#generating-pot-file), among others Loco Translate, Poedit.